# How do I reset an array in Swift when the user taps "Play Again"

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have posted my code below of a simple quiz app that asks users what the capital of a given state is. I have an array called `placeArray`, and each time a question from that array is asked, I call `removeAtIndex()` so as to not repeat questions.  When the game is over, `placeArray` is either partially or totally empty.

So when the user chooses to play again, how do I restore the array to its original state?

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var userInput:String = ""
    var processedAnswerString = ""
    var finalAnswerString = ""
    var questionString:String = ""
    var correctAnswerString = ""
    var gameInPlay : Bool = false
    var correctAnswers : Int = 0
    var wrongAnswers : Int = 0
    var numberOfRounds : Int = 0
    var indexNumber : Int = 0

    var placeArray = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California",    "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]

    var capitalArray = ["MONTGOMERY", "JUNEAU", "PHOENIX", "LITTLE ROCK", "SACRAMENTO", "DENVER" ,"HARTFORD", "DOVER", "TALLAHASSEE", "ATLANTA", "HONOLULU", "BOISE", "SPRINGFIELD", "INDIANAPOLIS", "DES MOINES", "TOPEKA", "FRANKFORT", "BATON ROUGE", "AUGUSTA", "ANNAPOLIS", "BOSTON", "LANSING", "SAINT PAUL", "JACKSON", "JEFFERSON CITY", "HELENA", "LINCOLN", "CARSON CITY", "CONCORD", "TRENTON", "SANTA FE", "ALBANY", "RALEIGH", "BISMARCK", "COLUMBUS", "OKLAHOMA CITY", "SALEM", "HARRISBURG", "PROVIDENCE", "COLUMBIA", "PIERRE", "NASHVILLE", "AUSTIN", "SALT LAKE CITY", "MONTPELIER", "RICHMOND", "OLYMPIA", "CHARLESTON", "MADISON", "CHEYENNE"]

    @IBOutlet weak var theTimer: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var thePlace: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var theGuess: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var theCorrectAnswerScore: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var theWrongAnswerScore: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        startGame()
        indexNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(50))
        thePlace.text = "What is the capital of \(placeArray[indexNumber])?"

    }

    var startTime = NSTimeInterval()
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var gameTime:Double = 100


    func startGame() {

        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    }

    func updateTime() {
    var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    var elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime
    var seconds = gameTime-elapsedTime
    if seconds > 0 {
        elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)
        theTimer.text = "\(Int(seconds))"
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Time's Up!", message: "You got \((correctAnswers/50)*100)% correct", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: .Default) { (action) in
            println("OK Pressed")
            self.wrongAnswers = 0
            self.correctAnswers = 0
            self.theGuess.text = ""
            self.gameTime = 100
            self.updateTime()
            self.startGame()
                  }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    }

    @IBAction func returnKeyPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    userInput = theGuess.text
    questionString = capitalArray[indexNumber]

    processedAnswerString = userInput.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())

    //strip white space from answer
    //allow either with or without capitalization
    if processedAnswerString.capitalizedString == questionString.capitalizedString {
        correctAnswers++
        numberOfRounds++

        gameTime = gameTime + (gameTime/10)
        if placeArray.count > 0 {
            placeArray.removeAtIndex(indexNumber)
            capitalArray.removeAtIndex(indexNumber)

            theCorrectAnswerScore.text = "Yes:  \(String(correctAnswers))"

            theGuess.text = ""

            println("The current placeArray count is \(placeArray.count)")
            println("The current capitalArray count is \(capitalArray.count)")
            println("The current indexNumber is \(indexNumber)")
        }
    } else {
        wrongAnswers++
        numberOfRounds++

        if gameTime - (gameTime/10) >= 0 {
            gameTime = gameTime - (gameTime/10)
        }

        if  placeArray.count > 0 {
            placeArray.removeAtIndex(indexNumber)
            capitalArray.removeAtIndex(indexNumber)
            theWrongAnswerScore.text = "No:  \(String(wrongAnswers))"
            theGuess.text = ""

        }
        println("The current placeArray count is \(placeArray.count)")
        println("The current capitalArray count is \(capitalArray.count)")
        println("The current indexNumber is \(indexNumber)")
    }

    indexNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(placeArray.count)))

    if placeArray.count != 0 {
        thePlace.text = "What is the capital of \(placeArray[indexNumber])?"
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You win!", message: "Nice work!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
            self.wrongAnswers = 0
            self.correctAnswers = 0
            self.theGuess.text = ""
            self.gameTime = 100
            self.updateTime()
            self.startGame()
            // ...
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
            // ...
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
            // ...
        }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to have a method that returns the initial version of the array then when you are finished or play again is called you can set the array using that method.

Alternatively you can create a 2nd array that holds your initial array data (copy of course) then remove the objects from the 2nd array. Once you hit play again just copy your initial array data back to the 2nd array and start again. The 2nd array would be the array displaying the questions and having data removed from it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create an helper method that returns your filled array.

You initialize the property you're using with it when the game starts (in your self.startGame() implementation for example), this way everytime the game starts the array will be full.

This would look like :

```
self.placeArray! = self.fullPlacesArray();
```

Comment: Thank you to all who took the time to answer.  I will try these suggestions.  I would up vote all of you, but I don't have enough reputation points to do it.